# Mesos slave doesn't offer resources

Tags: mesos

I have a mesos cluster with 1 master and 1 slave.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set up the configuration of both the master and the slave. And I can see the Mesos Web UI in http://master:5050 and the marathon UI in http://master:8080.

Also `Activated=1`, which means that the mesos slave is successfully connected to the mesos master I guess.

**However In the `Resources` section, the `Offered` property is always equal to `0`.**

The total amount of available CPU is `4`. `13GB` of RAM and `38GB` of disk.

Can anyone help with this issue ?

Comment: Ok I have just solved my problem ! The problem was not from the configuration. By inattention the command I runned was `echo "something"; sleep(5);` instead of `echo "something"; sleep 5;` Also I didn't understood well the attribute `offered`. This is not offers from mesos slave to mesos master but from mesos master to Marathon's scheduler